# Netbeans 8.1 + PHP, почему не работает автокомплит/подсказки и ctrl+click по имени метода?

Tags: php, netbeans

Сообственно, весь вопрос в заголовке. Теперь подробнее:

1. ctrl+click вроде работает, но только на стандартных методах и функциях самого PHP:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   В качестве примера использовался Laravel 5.5 + https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper, с которым по идее может работать с Netbeans, но почему-то не работает. Возможно что-то надо дополнительно включить?
2. Проблема с автокомплитом, не подсказывает методы класса/экземпляра класса даже в этом же файле.

Я раньше считал, что в Netbeans, по крайней для php, этого функционала просто нет/реализовано слишком криво, но сейчас склоняюсь к тому, что это моя какая-то локальная проблема. Есть ли такие функции в Netbeans, и если да, то как их правильно настроить?
Ubuntu 16.04
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.1 (Build 20151231-debian-8.1)
Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.1 Patch 1

Comment: потому что отсутствует документация к метода модели

Comment: а почему тогда ide helper не подхватывается? Кроме того, проблема не только в Laravel\Lumen, но и в Yii2. Также проблема наблюдается и для методов, которые созданы генераторами с уже готовыми описаниями методов. Есть какое-то описание, что необходимо прописывать для подхвата методов?

Comment: Вообще юзай phpstorm у него самые адекватные подсказки методов.

Comment: Удивлен, что комментарий про Шторм не был первым) Но все же, это не ответ. Вопрос про netbeans, если он не настраивается, то тогда раскошелюсь на шторм, но все-таки хочется выпрямить руки, а не залить все деньгами

Comment: у шторма есть триал плюс в нете много ключей и серверов для него... А про netbins он к примеру не парсил раньше
`/** @var Test $test */` и не выводил подсказок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, вот что помогло в моем случае:

Я использовал версию из репозитория (т.е. устанавливал через apt-get install netbeans) и php устанавливал как плагин. 
После того как я скачал специальную версию netbeans для php и проект проиндексировался, то и автодополнение, и переход стали нормально работать. Вот ссылки на них:

http://download.netbeans.org/netbeans/8.2/final/bundles/netbeans-8.2-php-linux-x86.sh

http://download.netbeans.org/netbeans/8.2/final/bundles/netbeans-8.2-php-linux-x64.sh

Остается вопрос, как настраивать универсальную версию netbeans